# How do I identify product code from a bank account number

Tags: india, banking, bank-account, savings-account, checking-account

I am trying to classify savings account and current account from a bank account number. Need to understand the pattern for Kotak Mahindra Bank

Comment: Why don't you ask the bank?

Comment: (Added "india" tag, based on the bank you quote... please correct if wrong). Do you have any evidence that there _is_ a distinction based on account number?

Comment: The likely answer is "not at all" - account numbers are generated semi randomly and then the difference is a marker in the database.

Comment: @TripeHound thank you for the tag. And I did figure out the same for other bank account numbers where I found the product code in the account number. Can't figure it out for Kotak Mahindra.

Comment: @TomTom the account numbers are not entirely random. Maybe the last 4-6 digits are which make it unique for every customer.

Comment: @JanDoggen I have been trying to reach the bank for the same as well.